# How to get the JSON-string value of a complex object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, serialization

I use jQuery to get `jsonData` from the server.  I don't know what the data is.  I would like to get the string value of the JSON object and write it in a `textarea` tag so I can debug.  How?  Please and thank you.

P.S. I am using .NET MVC and jQuery

Comment: Most (modern) browsers support `console.log()`. This is very useful since you do not neet to stringify the object. This function knows how to deal with objects.

Comment: @elusive Unless you're talking about IE (8 has a console.log, but it *still* does not understand objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on using JSON.stringify you should include json2.js to support older browsers.

Another route to solving your problem is to use firebug. It can show you each request along with the incoming and outgoing data.

Comment: The target end result is a view to display the JSON as text to a client, so Firebug would not be applicable.  I am assuming json2.js is the reference file with that function.  Where could I find it it?

Comment: json2.js can be found here: http://www.json.org/json2.js. If the end result is just to debug then adding a text box to your UI and setting its value is an unnecessary extra step.

Answer (score 2):

You could convert it back to JSON:

`$("the_textarea").val(JSON.stringify(data));`

It's actually quite readable.

Or use a tool like Firebug to dump it:

```
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

for most modern browsers (except IE <= 7) you can use `JSON.stringify(object)`